# ActivityNotFound even when Activity is present

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, start-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intent for editing plain text file with the installed file editor (if any)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539778/intent-for-editing-plain-text-file-with-the-installed-file-editor-if-any)

I am trying to open some text file which I have downloaded. When I start the activity with intent it gives ActivityNotFound Exception.

```
try {
    Uri path = Uri.parse(path+"/sampletext.txt");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    PackageManager packageManager = ctx.getPackageManager();
    intent.setType("text/plain") ;
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (list.size() > 0 ) {
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "text/plain");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        ctx.startActivity(intent) ;
    } 

} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace() ;
}
```

When I debugged, I found that the list.size is 1.

Is there any other information which I am missing?

Any kind of points would help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I am able to open the same file from the file browser, but not from my app.

Comment: @Merlin I do not want to edit the file.. I need to open the file for reading..

Comment: @Merlin, There the Mimetype is wrong, but here I am able to see the activity and still not able to launch..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActivityNotFound Exception is generally encoutered when there is no matching activity declared in the manifest file or registered by another application as a shared activity.

You may need to edit your path:

`Uri path = Uri.parse("file://" + path + "/sampletext.txt");`

a better way to do this is to use the convenience method:

`Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);`

but you would need to create a File object to use that method

Comment: When I debuged I found that quick office [On my HTC phone] is listed in the response which I got from queryIntentActivities(..).

Comment: Do you think file path would trigger a ANF Exception and not FileNotFound Exception?

Comment: Not really, but you never now what android does behind the scenes ... it's worth a try

Comment: No problem ... you're right though ... a FileNotFoundException or InvalidIntentDataException would make more sense and ultimately more helpful